# CSS3 Marquee / Ticker animation without space in the end

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm building a marquee/carousel effect with 2 collections of items. Looping both `item-collection` spans with `translateX` is not difficult ([here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1k3h2p0/)), but I don't like the empty space at the end of each loop.

[image]

Knowing that both collections might differ in width, how could I achieve an effect of "continuity" so after the first loop, the first collection (cyan) appears right after the second (magenta).

Any pointer to CSS or JS solutions is highly appreciated... =)

Comment: That is not really possible using CSS alone. There is a reason that most such slider scripts _clone_ some elements ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the marquee is big enough, you can swap one of the collections at mid animation.

This is as far as you can get with CSS alone, I think

```css
.marquee {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.marquee-content {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}
.item-collection-1 {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  animation: swap 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes swap {
  0%, 50% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50.01%,
  100% {
    left: 100%;
  }
}
.marquee-content:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}
.item1 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  width: 140px;
  background: cyan;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.item2 {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  background: magenta;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 15px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
/* Transition */

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="marquee-content">
    <span class="item-collection-1">
      <span class="item1"></span>
    <span class="item1"></span>
    <span class="item1"></span>
    <span class="item1"></span>
    <span class="item1"></span>
    <span class="item1"></span>
    <span class="item1"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="item-collection-2">
      <span class="item2"></span>
    <span class="item2"></span>
    <span class="item2"></span>
    <span class="item2"></span>
    <span class="item2"></span>
    <span class="item2"></span>
    <span class="item2"></span>
    <span class="item2"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: This is really interesting! It might suffice if we decide to make the marquee with a fixed width of <1000px. Upvoted and waiting for additional ideas from other people... ;)

Comment: It can suffice also if you have more than 2 collections